# Find Common Values in VIew

Tags: sql, oracle

using oracle database 12
I have this data

```
X1      X2              X3
42858   RRR08401000A    1
42858   RRR06113000A    1
42858   RRR05529000A    1
42858   RRR05529000B    1
42858   RRR49110RRRF    1
42858   34100000000A    1
42974   XYZ39916000A    1
42974   XYZ00949000B    2
42974   XYZ04888000A    1
42974   XYZ39915000B    1
42974   XYZ38535000A    1
42974   XYZ42350000A    1
42974   XYZ39746X0AA    1
42974   XYZ39743X0AA    1
42974   XYZ39923000A    1
42974   XYZ39745X0AA    1
42974   XYZ39744000A    1
42974   XYZ03058X0AB    1
42974   XYZ39759000A    1
42974   XYZ39760000B    1
42974   XYZ39762000A    1
42974   XYZ39748000A    1
42974   XYZ39749000B    1
42974   XYZ39747000A    1
42974   XYZ39742X0AA    1
42974   XYZ47965000B    1
42974   IUYI0902000E    1
42974   IUYI0897000F    1
42974   IUYI0909000F    1
42975   XYZ39916000A    1
42975   XYZ00949000B    2
42975   XYZ04888000A    1
42975   XYZ39915000B    1
42975   XYZ38535000A    1
42975   XYZ42350000A    1
42975   XYZ39746X0AA    1
42975   XYZ39743X0AA    1
42975   XYZ39923000A    1
42975   XYZ39745X0AA    1
42975   XYZ39744000A    1
42975   XYZ03058X0AB    1
42975   XYZ39759000A    1
42975   XYZ39760000B    1
42975   XYZ39762000A    1
42975   XYZ39748000A    1
42975   XYZ39749000B    1
42975   XYZ39747000A    1
42975   XYZ39742X0AA    1
42975   XYZ47965000B    1
42975   IUYI0902000E    1
42975   IUYI0897000F    1
42975   IUYI0909000F    1
```

What I want is to find common value in X2, then return X1
in this case, I want to get 42974 and 42975 because they shared the same X2

I use this query but it doesn't return anything

```
SELECT 
TT.X1
  FROM TEST12 TT
group by TT.WORK_ORDER 
having count(distinct TT.X2) = (select count (distinct tt2.X2) from TEST12 tt2)
```

but if I removed 42858 from the data, it returns 42974 and 42975

Please advise

thanks,
Journey Man

```
cREATE TABLE TEST12  (
     X1 NUMBER(8),
     X2 VARCHAR2(30),
     x3 NUMBER(8)
);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42858,'RRR08401000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42858,'RRR06113000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42858,'RRR05529000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42858,'RRR05529000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42858,'RRR49110RRRF',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42858,'34100000000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39916000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ00949000B',2);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ04888000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39915000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ38535000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ42350000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39746X0AA',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39743X0AA',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39923000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39745X0AA',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39744000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ03058X0AB',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39759000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39760000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39762000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39748000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39749000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39747000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ39742X0AA',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'XYZ47965000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'IUYI0902000E',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'IUYI0897000F',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42974,'IUYI0909000F',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39916000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ00949000B',2);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ04888000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39915000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ38535000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ42350000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39746X0AA',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39743X0AA',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39923000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39745X0AA',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39744000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ03058X0AB',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39759000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39760000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39762000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39748000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39749000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39747000A',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ39742X0AA',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'XYZ47965000B',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'IUYI0902000E',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'IUYI0897000F',1);
INSERT INTO TEST12 (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (42975,'IUYI0909000F',1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I understand that you want X1 values that share all their X2 values.
- This solution is for Oracle 11g R2

Here are some options.
There is limitation on the number of X2 elements since their being concatenated to a single string.

```
select    count (*)                                   as x2_within_group
         ,x2_elements
         ,listagg (x1,',') within group (order by x1) as x1_list


from     (select    X1
                   ,listagg (x2,',') within group (order by x2) as x2_list
                   ,count (*)                                   as x2_elements

          from      TEST12

          group by  X1
          )


group by  x2_list
         ,x2_elements
;
```

---

```
X2_WITHIN_GROUP  X2_ELEMENTS X1_LIST                      
---------------- ----------  ---------
2                23          42974,42975                   
1                6           42858
```

---

```
select    dense_rank () over (order by listagg (x2,',') within group (order by x2)) as group_id
         ,X1
         ,count (*)                                                                 as x2_elements
from      TEST12

group by  X1
;
```

---

```
  GROUP_ID      X1      X2_ELEMENTS
---------- ----------   ------------
         1      42858      6
         2      42975      23
         2      42974      23
```

Comment: Thanks Dudu, can we also add the total count similarity for X2?

Comment: @TRIEZEREN, Do you mean, how many X2 values are there per X1?

Comment: also will we be able to make it like pivot with additonal grouping rank

Comment: Thanks Dudu. it works, i am creating another question with the same data with pivot output

Comment: @TRIEZEREN great (P.s., if you liked the answer you may want to upvote it)

Answer (score 1):

Try a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.X1
FROM TEST12 T1
JOIN TEST12 T2 ON T1.X2 = T2.X2
    AND T1.X1 != T2.X2
```

The `DISTINCT` is needed in case there are *three* or more rows that share an `X2` value. If there are only ever at most *two* rows  that share an `X2` value, the `DISTINCT` keyword may be omitted.

Comment: errorORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.